# How to split a string and wrap it in a span tag and then output new code with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do you split multiple links and wrap them with a span tag and then loop through them to output them back inside the `a` tag. I seem to nearly be there as I have all the dates split into the `dateArr` below, just need a way loop them so I can output each one?

Dates are pulled through from dynamic PHP code so thats why I cant wrap them in the initial HTML so need to do it with JS.

[JSBIN DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ziwefi/edit?js,console,output)

**Current HTML**

```
<div class="award-date-section">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">2011 - 2015</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2006 - 2010</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2001 - 2005</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**This is how I want it to output:**

```
<div class="award-date-section">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="left-date">2011</span> <span class="middle"> - </span> <span class="right-date">2015</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="left-date">2006</span> <span class="middle"> - </span> <span class="right-date">2010</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="left-date">2001</span> <span class="middle"> - </span> <span class="right-date">2005</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var dates;
var splitDates = [];
var dateArr = [];


$(".award-date-section ul li a").each(function(i, el){

   dates = $(this).text();

   splitDates = dates.split('-');

   dateArr.push("<span class='left-date'>" + splitDates[0] + "</span><span class='middle'> - </span><span class='right-date'>" + splitDates[1] + "</span>");


});

for(var i = 0; i < dateArr.length; i++){
    $(".award-date-section ul li a").html(dateArr);
}
```

[JSBIN DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ziwefi/edit?js,console,output)

Comment: From the example in demo it looks like you have achieved what you want right ? And you have missed the index "i" in the line

     $(".award-date-section ul li a").html(dateArr[i]) 
which is correct in the demo

Comment: You have the output you want right?

Comment: What is the problem area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your loop u refer every time to every li and not one by one. You can remove the `for` and inside the `each` do:

```
$(this).html("<span class='left-date'>" + splitDates[0] + "</span><span class='middle'> - </span><span class='right-date'>" + splitDates[1] + "</span>")
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7d5aqkon/)

using `$(".award-date-section ul li a")` inside the for u ll get every time the last array element on each `li`

u can also use

```
for(var i = 0; i < dateArr.length; i++){
    $(".award-date-section ul li a:eq("+i+")").html(dateArr[i]);
}
```

[fiddle2](https://jsfiddle.net/knbeoz9c/)

Comment: Thank you so much, I was so close haha :) Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar need, php is generating:

```
    20 hours 35 minutes 23 seconds
```

so I did this

```
    var dates;
    var splitDates = [];
    var dateArr = [];


$(".thisone").each(function(i, el){
   dates = $(this).text();
  console.log($(this).text())

splitDates = dates.split(' ');

$(this).html("<span class='numeric'>" + splitDates[2] + "</span> <span 
class='alpha'>" + splitDates[3] + "</span> <span class='numeric'>" + 
splitDates[4] + "</span> <span class='alpha'>" + splitDates[5] + "</span> 
<span class='numeric'>" + splitDates[6] + "</span> <span class='alpha'>" + 
splitDates[7] + "</span>")
});


<body>
<div class="thisone">
  20 hours 35 minutes 23 seconds
</div>
</body>
```

But why does split dates have to start at 2?